# Where do you recommend loading in your jQuery library on WordPress site?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Where is the best place for performance to load in the jQUery library on a WordPress site? header.php? footer.php? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load jQuery in either place, but ideally you want to use WordPress' built-in function for adding scripts, including jQuery which they already have setup to do. It also allows you to include code in either the header or footer before the closing `</body>` tag.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Example, put this in your functions.php file and it will de-register the currently included copy of jQuery in WordPress and include the latest version hosted by Google's CDN:

```
<?php
    function my_init_method() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js', false, '1.6', true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}    

add_action('init', 'my_init_method');
?>
```

EDIT: The code example above sets the last argument to "true" which will place jQuery in the footer.

Answer (score 4):

YSlow recommendations would say the footer is the best place if you can manage it, because the JavaScript won't delay loading the page.  Put all your JavaScript just before the `</body>` tag.  Minify all of them and combine as many as possible to minimize downloads.